# Airflow 1.9 - Cannot get logs to write to s3

Tags: python, airflow

I'm running airflow 1.9 in kubernetes in aws.  I would like the logs to go to s3 as the airflow containers themselves are not long lived.

I've read the various threads and documents which describe the process but I still cannot get it working.  First a test that demonstrates to me that the s3 configuration and permissions are valid.   This is run on one of our worker instances.

Use airflow to write to an s3 file

```
airflow@airflow-worker-847c66d478-lbcn2:~$ id
uid=1000(airflow) gid=1000(airflow) groups=1000(airflow)
airflow@airflow-worker-847c66d478-lbcn2:~$ env |grep s3
AIRFLOW__CONN__S3_LOGS=s3://vevo-dev-us-east-1-services-airflow/logs/
AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID=s3_logs
AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER=s3://vevo-dev-us-east-1-services-airflow/logs/
airflow@airflow-worker-847c66d478-lbcn2:~$ python
Python 3.6.4 (default, Dec 21 2017, 01:37:56)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import airflow
>>> s3 = airflow.hooks.S3Hook('s3_logs')
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/utils/helpers.py:351: DeprecationWarning: Importing S3Hook directly from <module 'airflow.hooks' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/__init__.py'> has been deprecated. Please import from '<module 'airflow.hooks' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/hooks/__init__.py'>.[operator_module]' instead. Support for direct imports will be dropped entirely in Airflow 2.0.
  DeprecationWarning)
>>> s3.load_string('put this in s3 file', airflow.conf.get('core', 'remote_base_log_folder') + "/airflow-test")
[2018-02-23 18:43:58,437] {{base_hook.py:80}} INFO - Using connection to: vevo-dev-us-east-1-services-airflow
```

Now let's retrieve the file from s3 and look at the contents.  We can see everything looks good here.

```
root@4f8171d4fe47:/# aws s3 cp s3://vevo-dev-us-east-1-services-airflow/logs//airflow-test .
download: s3://vevo-dev-us-east-1-services-airflow/logs//airflow-test to ./airflow-test
root@4f8171d4fe47:/# cat airflow-test
put this in s3 fileroot@4f8171d4fe47:/stringer#
```

So it seems like the airflow s3 connection is good except airflow jobs do not use s3 for logging.  Here are the settings I have which I figure something is either wrong or I am missing something.

Env vars of running worker/scheduler/master instances are

```
airflow@airflow-worker-847c66d478-lbcn2:~$ env |grep -i s3
AIRFLOW__CONN__S3_LOGS=s3://vevo-dev-us-east-1-services-airflow/logs/
AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID=s3_logs
AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER=s3://vevo-dev-us-east-1-services-airflow/logs/
S3_BUCKET=vevo-dev-us-east-1-services-airflow
```

This shows that the s3_logs connection exists in airflow

```
airflow@airflow-worker-847c66d478-lbcn2:~$ airflow connections -l|grep s3
│ 's3_logs'              │ 's3'                    │ 'vevo-dev-
us-...vices-airflow' │ None   │ False          │ False                │ None                           │
```

I put this file https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py in place in my docker image.   You can see an example here on one of our workers

```
airflow@airflow-worker-847c66d478-lbcn2:~$ ls -al /usr/local/airflow/config/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root    root    4096 Feb 23 00:39 .
drwxr-xr-x. 1 airflow airflow 4096 Feb 23 00:53 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root    root    4471 Feb 23 00:25 airflow_local_settings.py
-rw-r--r--. 1 root    root       0 Feb 16 21:35 __init__.py
```

We have edited the file to define the REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER variable.  Here is the diff between our version and the upstream version

```
index 899e815..897d2fd 100644
--- a/var/tmp/file
+++ b/config/airflow_local_settings.py
@@ -35,7 +35,8 @@ PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{{ filename }}.log'
 # Storage bucket url for remote logging
 # s3 buckets should start with "s3://"
 # gcs buckets should start with "gs://"
-REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER = ''
+REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('core', 'remote_base_log_folder')
+

 DEFAULT_LOGGING_CONFIG = {
     'version': 1,
```

Here you can see that the setting is correct on one of our workers.

```
>>> import airflow
>>> airflow.conf.get('core', 'remote_base_log_folder')
's3://vevo-dev-us-east-1-services-airflow/logs/'
```

Based on the fact that REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER starts with 's3' and REMOTE_LOGGING is True

```
>>> airflow.conf.get('core', 'remote_logging')
'True'
```

I would expect this block https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/config_templates/airflow_local_settings.py#L122-L123 to evaluate to true and make the logs go to s3.

Please can anyone who has s3 logging working on 1.9 point out what I am missing?   I would like to submit a PR to the upstream project to update the docs as this seems to be a pretty common problem and as near as I can tell the upstream documents are not valid or somehow get misinterpreted frequently.

Thanks!  G.

Answer (score 3):

Yea, I also had trouble setting it up based just on the docs. I had to go over airflow's code to figure it out. There are multiple things you could have not done.

Some things to check:
1. Make sure you have the log_config.py file and it is in the correct dir: ./config/log_config.py. Also make sure you didn't forget the __init__.py file in that dir.
2. Make sure you defined the s3.task handler and set its formatter to airflow.task
3. Make sure you set airflow.task and airflow.task_runner handlers to s3.task

Here is a log_config.py file that works for me:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
# http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

import os

from airflow import configuration as conf

# TO DO: Logging format and level should be configured
# in this file instead of from airflow.cfg. Currently
# there are other log format and level configurations in
# settings.py and cli.py. Please see AIRFLOW-1455.

LOG_LEVEL = conf.get('core', 'LOGGING_LEVEL').upper()
LOG_FORMAT = conf.get('core', 'log_format')

BASE_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('core', 'BASE_LOG_FOLDER')
PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('scheduler', 'child_process_log_directory')

FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log'
PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{{ filename }}.log'

S3_LOG_FOLDER = 's3://your_path_to_airflow_logs'

LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'airflow.task': {
            'format': LOG_FORMAT,
        },
        'airflow.processor': {
            'format': LOG_FORMAT,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
        },
        'file.task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
        'file.processor': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_processor_handler.FileProcessorHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.processor',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
        # When using s3 or gcs, provide a customized LOGGING_CONFIG
        # in airflow_local_settings within your PYTHONPATH, see UPDATING.md
        # for details
        's3.task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.s3_task_handler.S3TaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            's3_log_folder': S3_LOG_FOLDER,
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
        # 'gcs.task': {
        #     'class': 'airflow.utils.log.gcs_task_handler.GCSTaskHandler',
        #     'formatter': 'airflow.task',
        #     'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
        #     'gcs_log_folder': GCS_LOG_FOLDER,
        #     'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        # },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL
        },
        'airflow': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'airflow.processor': {
            'handlers': ['file.processor'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'airflow.task': {
            'handlers': ['s3.task'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'airflow.task_runner': {
            'handlers': ['s3.task'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please include your definition of the s3.task handler. I'm not sure what this is or where it's supposed to go.

Comment: Hi, where is `./config/` supposed to go? I placed it in `$AIRFLOW_HOME` & it still says `ImportError: Unable to load custom logging from config.log_config.LOGGING_CONFIG due to No module named 'config'`. I even tried adding `$AIRFLOW_HOME` to the `$PYTHONPATH`.

Answer (score 0):

when deploying to k8 with the [official helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/airflow) I had to add the remote logging config also to the worker pods.
So this wasn't enough:

```
  AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOGGING: True
  AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID: s3_logs
  AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER: 's3://my-log-bucket/logs'
```

I also had to pass these vars to the workers

```
  AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES__AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOGGING: True
  AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES__AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID: s3_logs
  AIRFLOW__KUBERNETES_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES__AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER: 's3://my-log-bucket/logs'
```