# Airflow won't write logs to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

I tried different ways to configure Airflow 1.9 to write logs to s3 however it just ignores it. I found a lot of people having problems reading the Logs after doing so, however my problem is that the Logs remain local. I can read them without problem but they are not in the specified s3 bucket.

What I tried was first to write into the airflow.cfg file

```
# Airflow can store logs remotely in AWS S3 or Google Cloud Storage. Users
# must supply an Airflow connection id that provides access to the storage
# location.
remote_base_log_folder = s3://bucketname/logs
remote_log_conn_id = aws
encrypt_s3_logs = False
```

Then I tried to set environment variables

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_BASE_LOG_FOLDER=s3://bucketname/logs
AIRFLOW__CORE__REMOTE_LOG_CONN_ID=aws
AIRFLOW__CORE__ENCRYPT_S3_LOGS=False
```

However it gets ignored and the log files remain local.

I run airflow from a container, I adapted https://github.com/puckel/docker-airflow to my case but it won't write logs to s3. I use the aws connection to write to buckets in dags and this works but the Logs just remain local, no matter if I run it on an EC2 or locally on my machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found an answer using [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48969421/3808066)
which is most of the work I then had to add one more step. I reproduce this answer here and adapt it a bit the way I did:

Some things to check:

1. Make sure you have the `log_config.py` file and it is in the correct dir: `./config/log_config.py`.
2. Make sure you didn't forget the `__init__.py` file in that dir.
3. Make sure you defined the `s3.task` handler and set its formatter to `airflow.task`
4. Make sure you set airflow.task and airflow.task_runner handlers to s3.task
5. Set `task_log_reader = s3.task` in `airflow.cfg`
6. Pass the `S3_LOG_FOLDER` to `log_config`. I did that using a variable and retrieving it as in the following `log_config.py`.

Here is a log_config.py that works:

```py
import os

from airflow import configuration as conf


LOG_LEVEL = conf.get('core', 'LOGGING_LEVEL').upper()
LOG_FORMAT = conf.get('core', 'log_format')

BASE_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('core', 'BASE_LOG_FOLDER')
PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('scheduler', 'child_process_log_directory')

FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{{ ti.dag_id }}/{{ ti.task_id }}/{{ ts }}/{{ try_number }}.log'
PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE = '{{ filename }}.log'

S3_LOG_FOLDER = conf.get('core', 'S3_LOG_FOLDER')

LOGGING_CONFIG = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'airflow.task': {
            'format': LOG_FORMAT,
        },
        'airflow.processor': {
            'format': LOG_FORMAT,
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
        },
        'file.task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_task_handler.FileTaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
        'file.processor': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.file_processor_handler.FileProcessorHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.processor',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(PROCESSOR_LOG_FOLDER),
            'filename_template': PROCESSOR_FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
       's3.task': {
            'class': 'airflow.utils.log.s3_task_handler.S3TaskHandler',
            'formatter': 'airflow.task',
            'base_log_folder': os.path.expanduser(BASE_LOG_FOLDER),
            's3_log_folder': S3_LOG_FOLDER,
            'filename_template': FILENAME_TEMPLATE,
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        '': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL
        },
        'airflow': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'airflow.processor': {
            'handlers': ['file.processor'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'airflow.task': {
            'handlers': ['s3.task'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': False,
        },
        'airflow.task_runner': {
            'handlers': ['s3.task'],
            'level': LOG_LEVEL,
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Note that this way `S3_LOG_FOLDER` can be specified in `airflow.cfg` or as environment the variable `AIRFLOW__CORE__S3_LOG_FOLDER`.

Comment: in which section of `airflow.cfg` do we have to define `s3://bucketname/logs` as the value of `S3_LOG_FOLDER`? and if it is done like this then why `remote_base_log_folder = s3://bucketname/logs` has to be given?

Comment: Getting error like this: `aws-mwaa-local-runner-2_2-local-runner-1  | airflow.exceptions.AirflowConfigException: Configured task_log_reader 's3.task' was not a handler of the 'airflow.task' logger.` and airflow docker is not starting

Answer (score 0):

One more thing that leads to this behavior (Airflow 1.10):

If you look at `airflow.utils.log.s3_task_handler.S3TaskHandler`, you'll notice that there are a few conditions under which the logs, **silently**, will not be written to S3:

1) The logger instance is already `close()`d (not sure how this happens in practice)
2) **The log file does not exist on the local disk** (this is how I got to this point)

You'll also notice that the logger runs in a multiprocessing/multithreading environment, and that Airflow `S3TaskHandler` and `FileTaskHandler` do some very no-no things with the filesystem. **If assumptions about log files on disk are met, S3 log files will not be written, and nothing is logged nor thrown about this event.** If you have specific, well defined needs in logging it might be a good idea to implement all your own `logging` `Handlers` (see python `logging` docs) and disable all Airflow log handlers (see Airflow `UPDATING.md`).

Answer (score 0):

One more thing that may lead to this behaviour - botocore may be not installed.
Make sure when installing airflow to include s3 package `pip install apache-airflow[s3]`

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone else, here is what worked for me, answered in a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73652781/4187360